# Do individual cookie settings take precedence over those in the web.config?

Tags: java, php, .net, cookies

Suppose I have the following in my web.config in the appriopriate place:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

This sets all httpCookies as Secure by default. If I then have the following cookie:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("ResultsPerPage", "50");
cookie.Secure = false;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

1. Will this cookie have Secure set to True or to False?
2. Does this also apply if we try to set HttpOnly this way?
3. Does it work the other way around too (`requireSSL = "false"` and `cookie.Secure=true`)?
4. The above method is for .NET, but you can also set cookies in PHP and Java. If I use the comparable methods (web.xml/inline or php.ini/in the script) for Java and PHP, is the result the same as in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the HTTP response headers and cookies using a browser's dev console can give you insights into this. For the purpose of this answer, I have used ASP.Net and Chrome browser. To answer your question - Yes, individual cookie settings do take precedence over web.config settings.

Setting the config like this -

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
```

Results in a response header like this -

[image: response header config]

and cookies like this -

[image: cookies config]

Setting preferences for individual cookies in the code like this -

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("ResultsPerPage", "50");
cookie.Secure = false;
cookie.HttpOnly = false;
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

will result in response headers like this -

[image: response header code]

and cookies like this -

[image: cookie code]

You can verify if java and php have same behaviour by examining the cookies and response headers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: on a side note, I'm not sure if a cookie is the best place for storing  data like 'ResultsPerPage'. That is because this information is sent to the server with each request - and really, the server probably does not need that information. A good practice would be to fetch 'ResultsPerPage' and similar data on session start and store it in localstorage. Just my 2cents.